# Laravel: Global scope with whereHas and many-to-many relationshipi

Tags: mysql, unique, exists

I want to do a global scope filtering by a relation's field.

```
// The *apply* method of VersionScope file is:
$builder->whereHas('versions', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('version_id', '=', version()->id);
});

// Users'boot method has this line after parent:boot();
static::addGlobalScope(new VersionScope);
```

*versions* is a BelongsToMany relationship and *version()* is returning a Version object.

However I logged the query and is showing something like this:

```
select * 
from users 
where users.id = ?
where exists (
    select *
    from versions
    inner join user_version on user_version.version_id = versions.id
    where user_version.user_id = users.id
    and user_version.version_id = ?
)
```

The EXISTS subquery is working fine if it is the first relation, for example:

```
id|user_id|version_id
1 |1      |1
2 |1      |2
```

The query is working fine if version_id = 1, but I get empty result if version_id = 2. I'm not an MySQL expert so I don't really understand how work an EXISTS subquery with a JOIN inside.

But I see if I do something like next code all is working fine. But I need to filter all queries, so I think I need a global scope.

```
User::whereHas('versions', function($query) {
    return $query->where('version_id', version()->id)
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to change `whereHas('version_id'<...>` to simple `where('version_id'<...>`

Comment: Oups, sorry. The original code was with 'where' not 'whereHas', I did a mistake when posting the code. Updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't solved the issue but I have found how to avoid it. I don't know why it's happing:

If I have the following query and id is UNIQUE I don't get any result. However, if id is not UNIQUE I get the result as expected; so I have decided to remove the unique until I found another solution.

```
select * 
from users 
where users.id = ?
where exists (
    select *
    from versions
    inner join user_version on user_version.version_id = versions.id
    where user_version.user_id = users.id
    and user_version.version_id = ?
)
```

I don't know if this is a limitation of EXISTS subquery or maybe a bug of MySQL 5.7.12